# Round up a number inside a element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to round up a number to two digits after the comma. The number is located inside a span and has a specific class:

```
    <span class="roundup">1.982366834736872</span>
```

I've tried following code, but it did not work:

```
    $('.roundup').ready(function() {
        $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
    });
```

I'm new to Javascript. So can anyone help me out?

Comment: @ Hyg, kindly check the answer

Comment: just done it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path but need to correct few things as shown in the code

1. To wait until the DOM is ready, you need to use `ready` on the jQuery `$(document)` object, rather than `.roundup` itself.
2. Use `.each` to iterate through all roundup elements
3. As `roundup` elements are `<span>` not `<input>`, `.val` will not work but `.text` will.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.roundup').each(function() {
     $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="roundup">1.982366834736872</span>
```

Comment: @Hyg, happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
let value=$(".roundup").text();
let roundoff=Number(value).toFixed(2);
console.log(roundoff)
$(".roundup").text(roundoff);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="roundup">1.982366834736872</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update the code as below, you can use [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text in between the span.

Added a setTimeout of 3 seconds, so you can see the value is getting updated

You can remove setTimeout, for demo purpose only it has been added

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let value = $('.roundup').text();
  let roundedValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)

  // Updating the value adding a timeout so you can see the old value is replaced with new value
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.roundup').text(roundedValue)
  }, 3000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="roundup">1.982366834736872</span>
```

Single line

```
$('.roundup').text(parseFloat($('.roundup').text()).toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

val you are getting is a string "1,9823.." which contains a comma. so try using string operation as 
Number perations wont work.

if you want to take numer with two digits after comma tr following,

```
var a ="2,12"
let indexOfComma = a.indexOf(",")
var output= a.substr(0,indexOfComma+3)
```